# Fastest way to get closest data from multiple tables based on time

Tags: mysql, sql, time-series

I have three tables, with the following setup:

```
TEMPERATURE_1
  time
  zone (FK)
  temperature
TEMPERATURE_2
  time
  zone (FK)
  temperature
TEMPERATURE_3
  time
  zone (FK)
  temperature
```

The data in each table is updated periodically, but not necessarily concurrently (ie, the time entries are not identical).

I want to be able to access the closest reading from each table for each time, ie:

```
TEMPERATURES
  time
  zone (FK)
  temperature_1
  temperature_2
  temperature_3
```

In other words, for every unique time across my three tables, I want a row in the TEMPERATURES table, where the temperature_n values are the temperature reading closest in time from each original table.

At the moment, I've set this up using two views:

```
create view temptimes
as select time, zone 
  from temperature_1
union
  select time, zone
  from temperature_2
union
  select time, zone
  from temperature_3;

create view temperatures
as select tt.time,
          tt.zone,
          (select temperature 
           from temperature_1
           order by abs(timediff(time, tt.time))
           limit 1) as temperature_1,
          (select temperature 
           from temperature_2
           order by abs(timediff(time, tt.time))
           limit 1) as temperature_2,
          (select temperature 
           from temperature_3
           order by abs(timediff(time, tt.time))
           limit 1) as temperature_3,
from temptimes as tt
order by tt.time;
```

This approach works, but is too slow to use in production (it takes minutes+ for small data sets of ~1000 records for each temperature).

I'm not great with SQL, so I'm sure I'm missing the correct way to do this.  How should I approach the problem?

Comment: What is the significance of `zone`?

Comment: It's a foreign key to another table, and is what ties the temperature readings back to the rest of my data model.  Essentially, each zone will have an independent set of temperature readings (so at the end of the day, I want to be able to do 'select <something> from temperatures where zone=<something>')

Comment: It would really help if you provided a test case with sample data. Example: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/85a7b/1

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/648a9/1

Comment: can you try something like this - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5db76/4. There is a lot of looping that has to be done on DB side anyway, so I am not sure if that will make it faster. One way to do this fast is to use temp tables or materialized views, but that needs extra thinking )

Comment: @sapi what is the temperature sampling frequency?

Comment: The sampling frequency varies, and I don't want to normalise it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expensive part is where the correlated subqueries have to compute the time difference for every single row of each `temperature_*` table to find just *one* closest row for *one* column of *one* row in the main query.

It would be dramatically faster if you could just pick *one* row after and *one* row before the current time according to an *index* and only compute the time difference for these two candidates. All you need for that to be fast is an **index on the column `time`** in your tables.

I am ignoring the column `zone`, since its role remains unclear in the question, and it just add more noise to the core problem. Should be easy to add to the query.

Without an additional view, this query does all at once:

```
SELECT time
      ,COALESCE(temp1
            ,CASE WHEN timediff(time, time1a) > timediff(time1b, time) THEN
                (SELECT t.temperature
                 FROM   temperature_1 t
                 WHERE  t.time = y.time1b)
             ELSE
                (SELECT t.temperature
                 FROM   temperature_1 t
                 WHERE  t.time = y.time1a)
             END) AS temp1

      ,COALESCE(temp2
            ,CASE WHEN timediff(time, time2a) > timediff(time2b, time) THEN
                (SELECT t.temperature
                 FROM   temperature_2 t
                 WHERE  t.time = y.time2b)
             ELSE
                (SELECT t.temperature
                 FROM   temperature_2 t
                 WHERE  t.time = y.time2a)
             END) AS temp2

      ,COALESCE(temp3
            ,CASE WHEN timediff(time, time3a) > timediff(time3b, time) THEN
                (SELECT t.temperature
                 FROM   temperature_3 t
                 WHERE  t.time = y.time3b)
             ELSE
                (SELECT t.temperature
                 FROM   temperature_3 t
                 WHERE  t.time = y.time3a)
             END) AS temp3
FROM  (
  SELECT time
        ,max(t1) AS temp1
        ,max(t2) AS temp2
        ,max(t3) AS temp3

        ,CASE WHEN max(t1) IS NULL THEN
           (SELECT t.time FROM temperature_1 t
            WHERE  t.time < x.time
            ORDER  BY t.time DESC LIMIT 1) ELSE NULL END AS time1a
        ,CASE WHEN max(t1) IS NULL THEN
           (SELECT t.time FROM temperature_1 t
            WHERE  t.time > x.time
            ORDER  BY t.time      LIMIT 1) ELSE NULL END AS time1b
  
        ,CASE WHEN max(t2) IS NULL THEN
           (SELECT t.time FROM temperature_2 t
            WHERE  t.time < x.time
            ORDER  BY t.time DESC LIMIT 1) ELSE NULL END AS time2a
        ,CASE WHEN max(t2) IS NULL THEN
           (SELECT t.time FROM temperature_2 t
            WHERE  t.time > x.time
            ORDER  BY t.time      LIMIT 1) ELSE NULL END AS time2b

        ,CASE WHEN max(t3) IS NULL THEN
           (SELECT t.time FROM temperature_3 t
            WHERE  t.time < x.time
            ORDER  BY t.time DESC LIMIT 1) ELSE NULL END AS time3a
        ,CASE WHEN max(t3) IS NULL THEN
           (SELECT t.time FROM temperature_3 t
            WHERE  t.time > x.time
            ORDER  BY t.time      LIMIT 1) ELSE NULL END AS time3b
  FROM  (
      SELECT time, temperature AS t1, NULL AS t2, NULL AS t3 FROM temperature_1
      UNION ALL
      SELECT time, NULL AS t1, temperature AS t2, NULL AS t3 FROM temperature_2
      UNION ALL
      SELECT time, NULL AS t1, NULL AS t2, temperature AS t3 FROM temperature_3
      ) AS x
  GROUP BY time
  ) y
ORDER BY time;
```

[**->sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/363f7/12)

#### Explain

**suqquery x** replaces your view `temptimes` and brings the temperature into the result. If all three tables are in sync and have temperatures for all the same points in time, the rest is not even needed and extremely fast.
For every point in time where one of the three tables has no row, the temperature is being fetched as instructed: take the "closest" one from each table.

**suqquery y** aggregates the rows from `x` and fetches the previous time (`time1a`) and the next time (`time1b`) according to the current time from each table where the temperature is missing. These lookups should be fast using the index.

The **final query** fetches the temperature from the row with the closest time for each temperature that's actually missing.

This query could be simpler if MySQL would allow to reference columns from more than one level above the current subquery. Bit it cannot. Works just fine with in **PostgreSQL**: [->sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/363f7/2)

It also would be simpler if one could return more than one column from a correlated subquery, but I don't know how to do that in MySQL.

And it would be *much* simpler with *CTEs* and *window functions*, but MySQL doesn't know these modern SQL features (unlike other relevant RDBMS).

Comment: Thanks - I finally understand this query, and it works extremely quickly :)

Comment: One question, actually: why take max(t1) as temp1 (etc)?  I don't understand why the maximum temperature would be significant

Comment: @sapi: Could be `min()` just as well. Or even `sum()`. The point is (provided there cannot be two rows for the same `time` in one of the base tables), there is at most *one* temperature value per column and the rest is `NULL`. Either of these aggregate functions will only consider the non-null value (or result in `NULL` if there is none). More about that in the manual [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html).

Answer (score 0):

The reason that this is slow is that it requires 3 table scans to calculate and order the diferences.

I assume that you allready have indexes on the time zone columns - at the moment they won't help becuase of the table scan problem.

There are a number of options to avoid this depending on what you need and what the data collection rates are.

You have already said that the data is collected periodically but not concurrently. This suggests a few options.

1. To what level of significance do you need the temp data - the day, the hour, the minute etc. Store the time zone info to that level of significance only (or have another column that does) and do your queries on that.
2. If you know that the 3 closets times will be within a certain time frame (hour, day etc) put in a where clause to limit the calculation to those times that are potential candidates. You are effectively constructing histogram type buckets - you will need a calendar table to do this efficiently.
3. Make the comparison unidirectional i.e. limit consideration to only those times after the time you are looking for, so if you are looking for 12:00:00 then 13:45:32 is a candidate but 11:59:59 isn't.

I understand what you are trying to accomplish - ask yourself why and if a simpler solution will neet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that you don't take the closest time, but you take the first time on or before a given time.  The reason for this is simple:  generally the data for a given time is what is known at that time.  Incorporating future information is generally not a good idea for most purposes.

With this change, you can modify your query to take advantage of an index on `time`.  The problem with an index on your query is that the function precludes the use of the index.

So, if you want the most recent temperature, use this instead for each variable:

```
      (select temperature 
       from temperature_1 t2
       where t2.time <= tt.time
       order by t2.time desc
       limit 1
      ) as temperature_1,
```

Actually, you can also construct it like this:

```
      (select time 
       from temperature_1 t2
       where t2.time <= tt.time
       order by t2.time desc
       limit 1
      ) as time_1,
```

And then join the information for the temperature back in.  This will be efficient, with the use of an index.

With that in mind, you could actually have two variables `time_1_before` and `time_1_after`, for the best time on or before and the best time on or after.  You can use logic in the select to choose the nearest value.  The joins back to the temperature should be efficient using an index.

But, I will reiterate, I think the last temperature on or before may be the best choice.

Comment: Would the logic you describe in the select add much overhead to the call?  It sounds pretty much like what I'm after.  (I agree that if the data were logged instantaneously upon step change, then the last on or before would be the correct choice.  However, for periodic logging, it seems to me to be more accurate to take the nearest reading, as there is no way of knowing where in the interval the change occurred.)

Comment: The query should run efficiently with an index on the `time` field.  There is overhead, but it is should not be particularly expensive with an index.  For periodic logging, I would suggest a modified approach that would start with a table of the period time values, with a lookup such as suggested in my solution.

Comment: Would using the temptimes view that I described in the question be suitable for the initial table of values, before using the two variable lookup logic?

Comment: Your temptimes view is rather expensive, because it does the union and then removes duplicates.  Having an actual table would make the query more efficient.